# Javascript/HTML: Need to change font size

Tags: html, fonts, font-size

I have a question that has been hindering for a while,
https://hastebin.com/fuyipereta.xml
This is my HTML file,  is my script
I need to know how to change text size in this instance, please help me
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to make all the HTML stuff in javascript?

It looks like there's no div with the ID of span. Since you ARE assigning (albeit, in a very strange way) an ID to the span, you could do something like

`var fsize = document.getElementById("highlight")`

`fsize.style.fontSize = '40px';`

after you're doing the `document.write`

---

You should seriously considering just making the span in HTML and assigning a class/id, then changing the size with CSS. It's just simpler.

There are a lot of other issues with your code, but this should specifically fix the font size.